# AVFAudio crash on performSelector:withObject:finishedPlaying

Tags: ios, avplayer, avaudioplayer, avaudiosession

I'm trying to troubleshoot this crash issue:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x0000000180274430 objc_msgSend + 16
1   Foundation                      0x0000000181a132e4 __NSThreadPerformPerform + 340 (NSThread.m:1265)
2   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180fbf77c __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 24 (CFRunLoop.c:1982)
3   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180fbf6fc __CFRunLoopDoSource0 + 88 (CFRunLoop.c:2017)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180fbef84 __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 204 (CFRunLoop.c:2053)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180fbcb5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2920)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x0000000180edcc58 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 436 (CFRunLoop.c:3245)
7   GraphicsServices                0x0000000182d88f84 GSEventRunModal + 100 (GSEvent.c:2245)
8   UIKit                           0x000000018a6355c4 UIApplicationMain + 236 (UIApplication.m:3956)
```

Upon further investigation, I found out the crash was on AVFAudio: 
**performSelector:withObject:finishedPlaying**

I'm not sure who calls this because I'm not calling this function, and I don't implement the AVAudioPlayer delegate.

I'm simply playing audio when a user tap on something. My initial guess was the audio is still playing and the view controller gets dismissed. However, I couldn't reproduce it. My call to play audio is like this:

```
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];
    [self.audioPlayer play];
```

and when the controller disappeared I call this:

```
- (void) viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [self.audioPlayer stop];
}
```

Also, I have strong reference to the AVAudioPlayer

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) AVAudioPlayer *audioPlayer;
```

Not sure if this affects it but I want to make sure the user will hear the sound even if it's on mute:

```
NSError *setCategoryErr = nil;
NSError *activationErr  = nil;
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryErr];
[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setActive:YES error:&activationErr];
```

TIA

Comment: Can you post the entire crash log if possible?

Comment: I updated the crash log, don't think that'll help though. I had to look for performSelector:withObject:finishedPlaying by debugging the registers.I also figured out that finishedPlaying is a private method that gets called  when the audio is finished playing from the system call. I have [self.audioPlayer stop] on viewDidDisappear, which should be called before the dealloc.

Comment: You could potentially swizzle out that method so that you can put a breakpoint to see when it's being called (e.g. after `stop` or `dealloc`).

Comment: @GuyKogus Could you elaborate? It's a system call, and I didn't swizzle the method manually.

Comment: You know the class and method that's failing, so you can use swizzling to catch the call to that method and put a breakpoint in there. It's been a while since I've done swizzling, so check out an article like this to help you: https://blog.newrelic.com/2014/04/16/right-way-to-swizzle/ It's a bit tricky so sorry I couldn't explain it better in a comment like this.

Comment: @GuyKogus I see, I know the method that's failing, so I tried symbolic breakpoint and that's how I figured out that's a private system call which occurs when the audio player finish with the sound. What I don't understand is that why this still gets called when I already have [self.audioPlayer stop] when it disappear? My guess now is somehow it gets deallocated before the viewDidDisappear gets called.

Comment: That wouldn't be possible since you have a `strong` reference to the player. Maybe with more code we could help debug more...?

Comment: @GuyKogus I thought that too. I'm thinking maybe timing issue. 
If I have: 
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file1 error:nil];
[self.audioPlayer play];

say file1 is 2 seconds, and at 1.80 seconds, I changed to file2:
self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:file2 error:nil];
[self.audioPlayer play];
Do you think this could cause it?

Comment: Potentially, depending on the `delegate`. I just had a look now at the documentation and apparently it's marked as `unowned(unsafe) var delegate: AVAudioPlayerDelegate?` Maybe this is causing your problems?

Comment: @GuyKogus ,I don't have the delegate set for it though, and the finishedPlaying still gets called.

Comment: If you disable your `AVAudioSession` calls does it make a difference?

Comment: @ordinaryman09 You might be on to something as you mentioned in your comment above^^ with the file1 and file2 scenario. Try calling `[self.audioPlayer stop]` and `self.audioPlayer = nil;` right before playing a new audio file here `self.audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];`

Comment: @ordinaryman09 Did you have any luck with finding the source of that problem? I have the same stacktrace, also leading to that selector and no delegates in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me share my findings (no matter how scarce), may be they will help someone. I did not use AVAudioPlayer's delegate in my code, but I had a collection of sounds which were supposedly playing and once in a while I iterated over that collection and deleted sounds with false `isPlaying` field. It resulted in a crash mentioned above, though it was extremely rare. Your situation may look completely different (like having a single AVAudioPlayer which gets deleted together with encompassing class), but the effect is probably the same.

What I changed to finally get rid of the bug: I made AVAudioPlayerDelegate, which deleted the sound that just finished playing.

My theory is the following. The sound playing code runs on another thread and when it finishes, it sets `isPlaying` to false (or whatever results in it returning false) **and** tries to call the delegate's `finishedPlaying` on UI thread, which involves some minor delay. Now what happens if you delete the AVAudioPlayer between those 2 events is probably what results in attempt to access the deleted player's `delegate?.finishedPlaying`.

It is just a speculative guesswork, but it seems to fit the observed results: the crash, why it is so difficult to reproduce and why my changes fixed it.